# SSRS, record spans muliple pages, print current record id in footer

Tags: reporting-services, footer, record

I have a large SSRS report where the data(tables & subreports) span multiple pages(2-4). The report is a printed survey that the user will fill out and mail in. I would like to add a footer with the record id in the footer so if the pages get mixed up, the users will know what page goes to what survey/business.

The clients print out multiple survey at a time. The surveys are dynamically created and the length is variable base on the businesses data.

Does anyone know how to put row level data in a SSRS report footer?

Comment: What do you mean by current id? Is there one ID for the whole report are or you expecting to print the last record generated on a page?

Comment: The report prints out multiple records. It takes a parameter of business ids (up to 999). Each id creates a multi-page survey. The part that makes this hard is the sub-reports don't return a fixed size, so I don't know where the page break are for each top level record (this business).

Answer (score 0):

I would use the ReportItems syntax e.g.

`= ReportItems!id.Value`